# Invalid assignment left-hand side, javascript

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I am sure I am doing something silly here:

```
var addhtml = '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">'
+= '<div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>'
+= '<div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>'
+= '<div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>'
+= '</div>';             // invalid assignment left-hand side
console.log(addhtml);
```

And Netbeans is telling me that `invalid assignment left-hand side` error.

Whats wrong ?

Comment: what's += doing there? a + is what you want

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need `+=` to concatenate, you just need `+`

This is ok

```
var addhtml = '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">'
+ '<div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>'
+ '<div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>'
+'<div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>'
+ '</div>';         
console.log(addhtml);
```

Comment: YESSSS.. thats what I meant to do.. simple string concatenation.. *smack_self* .. :) Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a clue on a similar bug I was facing. I was trying `$(this).data('var') = true` instead of `$(this).data('var', true);`

Answer (score 9):

`+=` means "take the thing on the left, add this to it, and store the result in the thing on the left". The left-hand side of your `+=` is a literal (the first one is `'<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">`). You can't assign to literals.

Put it another way, `a += b` basically means `a = a + b`. You can see how that doesn't work if `a` is a literal rather than a variable.

You just want `+` there:

```
var addhtml = '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">'
+ '<div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>'
+ '<div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>'
+ '<div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>'
+ '</div>';
console.log(addhtml);
```

To give you an idea of the difference between `+` and `+=`:

```
var a, b;
a = "foo";
b = a + "bar";  // Doesn't modify `a`
console.log(a); // "foo"
console.log(b); // "foobar"
```

vs.

```
var a, b;
a = "foo";
b = a += "bar"; // Modifies `a` (assigning the result to `b` is unusual -- very -- but valid)
console.log(a); // "foobar" - note it's changed
console.log(b); // "foobar"
```

---

**Off-topic**:

I'd also recommend indenting the subsequent lines of the assignment statement, but that's just style:

```
var addhtml = '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">'
    + '<div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>'
    + '<div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>'
    + '<div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>'
    + '</div>';
console.log(addhtml);
```

Answer (score 2):

The assignment (=) is not necessary, you can just use +. There are two other ways to construct multiline strings:

```
// method 1: use continuation \
 var addhtml = '\
        <div id="leftbio" class="left-float"> \
            <div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div> \
            <div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div> \
            <div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div> \
        </div>';

//method 2: use an array and join the elements
 var addhtml = [
       '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">',
       ' <div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>',
       ' <div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>',
       ' <div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>',
       '</div>'
     ].join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

`x += y` is shorthand for `x = x + y` which is not what you want here.

Either use:

```
var addhtml = '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">';
addhtml += '<div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>';
addhtml += '<div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>';
addhtml += '<div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>';
addhtml += '</div>';
```

or:

```
var addhtml = '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">'
    + '<div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>'
    + '<div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>'
    + '<div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>'
    + '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need =

```
var addhtml = '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">'
    + '<div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>'
    + '<div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>'
    + '<div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>'
    + '</div>';             // invalid assignment left-hand side
    console.log(addhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain attribution operators like `+=`.

```
var addhtml = '<div id="leftbio" class="left-float">'
              + '<div id="bioname">e["screen_name]</div>'
              + '<div id="biophoto"><img src="e["profile_image_url"]"/></div>'
              + '<div id="biodetails">e["description"]</div>'
              + '</div>';             // invalid assignment left-hand side
console.log(addhtml);
```