# Javascript invalid assign left hand side

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid assignment left-hand side, javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503409/invalid-assignment-left-hand-side-javascript)

```
                   var htmlToAdd = '<label for="A'+indexNr+'" class="PriceLabel">Min</label>'
                                += '<input style="width:3em" name="B'+indexNr+'" id="B'+indexNr+'" type="text"  />'
                                += '<label for="C'+indexNr+'" class="MaxPriceLabel">Max</label>'
                                += <input style="width:3em" name="D'+indexNr+'" id="D'+indexNr+'" type="text"  />';
```

I am trying to create html as string and then use append to some another html element. Firebug is giving me

invalid assignment left-hand side

```
    [Break On This Error] += '<input style=...rcentage'+indexNr+'" type="text" />'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `+=` with `+`

`+=` means "Take the variable on the left, append what is on the right to it, then assign back to the variable" … but you have a string to the left of each one, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for @Quentin answer...or if you want to do it with `+=`, you have to do fallowing-

```
var htmlToAdd = '<label for="A'+indexNr+'" class="PriceLabel">Min</label>'
    htmlToAdd += '<input style="width:3em" name="B'+indexNr+'" id="B'+indexNr+'" type="text"  />'
    htmlToAdd += '<label for="C'+indexNr+'" class="MaxPriceLabel">Max</label>'
    htmlToAdd += <input style="width:3em" name="D'+indexNr+'" id="D'+indexNr+'" type="text"  />';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use "+=" than you must give variable name on the left hand side other wise